# Mac boot partition FFFF (High Sierra)

Tags: macos, high-sierra, partition, startup

I know many people have had similar kind of issues and I tried to fix this with the answers I found but with no luck.

- Device: iMac 27" mid 2011
- OS: Latest High Sierra (I think the recovery mode is maybe the Lion version?)

I have Linux partition with High Sierra, and been using it with no problems at all. Now I did a Bootcamp partition too and installed Windows 7. After that, I am now unable to boot to Mac and in recovery mode I can see that the main partition type is now FFFFFF-FFFF...

The partitions in a nutshell are like:

- High sierra, ~850 GB
- Linux, ~100 GB <- This can be deleted
- Bootcamp, ~49 GB <- This can be deleted

What I have tried:

I did the `gpt destroy disk0` and after that added all the volumes back with

```
gpt create -f disk0

gpt add -i 1 -b 40 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B /dev/disk0

gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 1662109312 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
```

and so on..
then then trying to verify the volumes with `diskutil verityVolume disk0s2` I get 
"Error starting file system verification for disk0s2: Unrecognized file system (-69846)"

Now I am at the point where I do not know what to do anymore.

Where I started:

[image: diskutil-list-original]

[image: gpt-show-disk0-original]

And where I am now:

[image: final-stage]

[image]

1. I just want a easiest way to get MacOS back to working with the data that's in there if possible and all the other partitions are disposable.
2. Or I would like to know how to just format the drive and remove all the partitions so I can do a clean install (plan B).

All comments appreciated! Thanks!

Edit1: Oops I forgot that of course I can just format the drive via the graphical disk utility tool.

Comment: Plan B - open Disk Utility from recovery mode and blow it all away

Comment: @goofology Please avoid answering in comments and consider writing a proper answer post. "All comments appreciated" was not to  be taken literally.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii I disagree with your advice.  My comment was useful, but **not** worthy of a "proper answer", as it does not address both of OP's questions, and it is likely something OP is already aware of or could easily find, as he has clearly already found his way into recovery mode.  Not to mention, OP's **literal** "comments appreciated...".  Please avoid critiquing helpful comments and consider adding value to the conversation instead.

Comment: @goofology You can definitely write an answer specifically for part 2 as OP gave a choice. They want to know how to format and do a clean install.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii I'm aware that I **could** submit an answer, but 1, it's not properly helpful to the OP's primary desired outcome, and 2, it's stupidly simple and not deserving of an "award" in my opinion, thus unworthy to post as an answer. Put another way, it's a "freebie" - I wouldn't charge a client for explaining they simply need to click on the "Disk Utility" button that's staring them in the face.  I appreciate your intent to ensure quality answers, but in this case, my contribution, while useful, does not meet the 'quality bar'.

Comment: Seems OP has already realized his oversight, and @David Anderson's comment is a candidate for a **real** answer.  :)  It's not uncommon in my experience for potential solutions to be proposed in comments and only finalized as answers when confirmed as properly useful.

Comment: @DavidAnderson https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qzlrnxkp1d408s/gpt.jpg?dl=0 for some reason cannot do that, looks like I am doing something wrong?? The indexes 1 and 2 went fine with that command.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and for trying to help me. I ended up going with plan B since I don't have enough spare time in my hands to fiddle around. I am now installing Lion. I guess I can update to High Sierra from AppStore later.